# Displaying the page titles based on the pages dynamically in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to display page titles dynamically based on the pages displayed.

Hi i am having a site developed in codeigniter php but the problem is need to display page titles dynamically based on the pages.These pages titles should be fetched from database.Can anyone have any idea how to do this.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url('testimonial/index');
    $config['total_rows'] =   $this->testimonial_model->record_count();//here we will count all the data from the table
    $config['per_page'] = 6;//number of data to be shown on single page
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["records2"] = $this->testimonial_model->get_all_testimonials($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data['records7'] = $this->index_model->get_all_banners();
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();//create the link for pagination
    $data['mainpage'] = "testimonial";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_all_testimonials($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('T.*');
    $this->db->from('testimonials AS T');
    $this->db->where(array('T.status'=>1));
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row testimonialpage"> 
<div class="col-md-12 testimonialpage">         
    <div class="col-md-9 testimonials" >    
    <div class="testimonialpagetext">       
    </div>  
    <?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>    
    <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>          
    <div class="testimonial1">          
    <div class="testimonialtext1">      
    <?php echo $r->description;?>   
    <ul class="founders">
        <li class="founder"><?php echo $r->client_name;?></li>
        <li class="founder"><?php echo $r->founder;?></li>          
    </ul>
    </div>      
    </div>      
    <?php endforeach ;endif;?>  
    <div class="pagination"><?php echo $links; ?></div> 
    </div>  
    </div>      
    </div>
```

Comment: you can get uri section for pages. so you can identify the page and than fetch title from the database for that page

Comment: @GopalBhuva can you explain that little

Answer (score 0):

For Ex:: Your url is `www.example.com/controller/register` when you get uri segment(2) means you will get (register). based on this you can identify that you are on the register page. now you can find the title for register page from your database.

Comment: But how to fetch that title name in controller

Comment: you can directly write model code.. in view file i am also using in my one of project and it working fine.. write this code in your view `$title=$this->Your_model->function(argument)`

Comment: I have my testimonial code once i open the page it should display the title as testimonials can you check in that

Answer (score 0):

Every time i build an application with Codeigniter, i use a Class **MY_Controller** that extends CI_Controller, inside **application/core** like bellow:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    protected $view_data;

    function __construct() {
        //......
    }
}
```

Any controller inside **application/controllers** will extend the **MY_Controller** instead of **CI_Controller**.

Now in the constructor of **MY_Controller** you can do something like:

```
$page = $this->uri->segment(2); (2 or 3 or 4 etc, depends on your structure)
```

Load your model, execute your query and add the result in **$this->view_data** like:

```
$pageTitle = $this->your_model->getPageTitle($page);
$this->view_data['page_title'] = $pageTitle['page_title'];
```

Example of getPageTitle in your model:

```
public function getPageTitle($page) {
    $qry = $this->db->select('page_title')
                ->from('pages')
                ->where('page', $page)
                ->get();
        if ($qry->num_rows() > 0)
            return $qry->row_array();
        return false;
}
```

### Watch out the sample names i gave, you should change those!

To load your view, pass the variable **$this->view_data** as parameter and in your view do something like

```
<title><?= $page_title ?></title>
```

Comment: page_title it will be the column name or we should give the name

Comment: Check edit. I tried to show you a simple model function to get the page_title from model. I don't know the schema of your database tho...

Comment: Did you configure everything to your project or just c/p it directly? You need to implement the whole functionality i gave to you in your project. In index.php of the root of your application change the ENVIRONMENT to development and read the errors.

Comment: I have implemented everything in my project getting error as undefined variable

Comment: I have changed that but now it is displaying the URL which is displaying in the browser displaying the same for page title

Comment: Sorry but it is not possible to debug your code! You need to work around the solution i gave to you (if you find it useful) and get the job done.